# Multithreaded Processing of data using Spring Batch

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch 2.1.8.RELEASE. I have a file which consists of some Header information followed by some records which I need to process.

I have a step which makes use of chunk oriented processing. The step contains an implementation of the ItemReader and ItemWriter. The ItemReader implementation is thread-safe while the ItemWriter is not.

I want to use the Header information before I process( or write) any of the records. How do I ensure this while continuing to use the chunk oriented processing?

**Proposed Solution :**
One solution could be to write a pre-process step and extract the header information.

Is there any alternate solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try an approch similar to one describer in [Spring Batch Item Reader - use skippedLinesCallback to set input field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125501/spring-batch-item-reader-use-skippedlinescallback-to-set-input-field-names/18127165#18127165) :  you must inject the headerCallback bean into your reader (and processor or writer) and use it safely because the headerCallback bean has been called from your reader.

I hope I was clear, English is not my native language (and I'm in troubles with past tenses '-_-)

Comment: Thanks a lot bellabax, but just to clarify the question, I have a multi-line header. 
Also,I have set the throttle-limit > 1 for scalibilty, in that case, how can I ensure that the chunk containing the header is processed (or written) before any other chunk ?

Comment: I don't know this specific behaviour,but for FlatFileItemReader the skipLines property is managed before all next read and should works