# How to handle dynamic columns changes using FlatFileItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to read values from a specific column name in a CSV file

I understood that I need statically declare on all column names this way:

```
 lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"name1","name2","name3"});
```

if for example I want to read only the values of column name2 ill do it this way:

```
public class PushItemFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<MyObject > {

    @Override
    public MyObject mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        MyObject myobject= new MyObject ();
        pushItemDTO.setName2(fieldSet.readString("name2"));
        return myobject;
    }
}
```

but tomorrow I might get different  CSV file like this:

name7,name2,name9,name19

than ill need to recompile my code after modifying

```
lineTokenizer.setNames...
```

I always want to retrieve values from a specific column name(in this case name2) while not caring about others. how I could do it dynamically without statically declare my column names as show in this example?

As suggested I tried to do something like this:

```
 public FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO>();
        itemReader.setSkippedLinesCallback(new LineCallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleLine(String line) {
                head=line;
            }
        });

        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("c:/newfile.txt"));
        return itemReader;
    }

 @Bean
    public LineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper(String head) {
        DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);

//need to inject into here somehow the head on each execution
            lineTokenizer.setNames( 
            });

//need to inject into here somehow the head on each execution
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(PushItemDTO.class);


        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PushItemFieldSetMapper());
```

But how I am going to pass the head into linemapper() ?

Comment: use a "step" scoped object to dynamically change columns name

Comment: Isnt a way to just retrieve values of a specific column name? or mybe retrieve the current column names of csv file(by parsing first line)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Batch Item Reader - use skippedLinesCallback to set input field names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125501/spring-batch-item-reader-use-skippedlinescallback-to-set-input-field-names)

Comment: check for my previous comment

Comment: Yes i tried. I am using Java config and I didt nail this down. could you answer this question with practical example how you would do that? thank you.

Comment: I started first impl of your idea could you continue from there?

Comment: sorry, i haven't opportunities to create an example with javaconfig or XML

Comment: But I dont understand.. the callback I am getting of LineCallbackHandler is only  on execution time after I already set the lineMapper() how I gonna inject it into there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68428/discussion-between-luca-basso-ricci-and-rayman).

Answer (score 0):

```
For setting dynamic names and ranges in flatFile reading, 

FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();

String[] namesArray = getNamesArray() //Dynamically get Names
Range[] rangeArray = getRanges() // Dynamically get ranges

// and set names and columns
tokenizer.setNames(namesArray);
tokenizer.setColumns(rangeArray);
```